# Initiate Vert.x cluster manager from existing HazelCast cluster running outside

Tags: docker, hazelcast, vert.x

I am new to use the Hazelcast/Vert.x technology.

I have docker desktop installed on my laptop. Using docker I created a Hazelcast cluster with two nodes using TCP-IP and for that I am using hazelcast/hazelcast:4.0.2 image.

```
<multicast enabled="false"></multicast>
<tcp-ip enabled="true">
  <member>x.x.x.x:5701</member>
  <member>x.x.x.x:5702</member>
</tcp-ip>
```

I have checked the docker service logs for two members which shows that both members a successfully created and joined without any error. Also, created a Hazelcast-client JAVA program in my laptop using IntelliJ IDE through which I successfully connected to the Hazelcast cluster which is running inside docker.

I am stuck when I am trying to use Vert.x Hazelcast and want to connect existing Hazelcast cluster which is running inside docker. As per documentation Vert.x Hazelcast don't support Hazelcast client or smart client. What I want is to instantiate Vert.x Clustermanager which will point to that existing Hazelcast cluster running outside in docker. I have used Hazelcast.getHazelcastInstanceByName("") method inside the JAVA code which did not find the existing Hazelcust cluster. Actually my existing project has a module which is already using embeded Vert.x Hazelcast cluster with one node. To enable high availability and zero downtime deployment we want to enable Hazelcast cache for the module.

Is that possible to get the existing hazelcast instance in the JAVA code. I have gone through almost all google links for last few weeks but did not able to find the existing cluster instance using TCP/IP. But yes using hazelcast client I can connect to the outside cluster but I want to instantiate Vert.x Clustermanager which require Hazelcast instance not HazelcastClient instance. This is I am specifically looking just to minimize change in existing code.

Answer (score 0):

Vertx does not support Hazelcast client (as you mentioned and as is stated in [Vertx: Using an existing Hazelcast cluster](https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-hazelcast/java/#_using_an_existing_hazelcast_cluster)). That means that you always need to start a Hazelcast instance embedded in your Vertx java process.

Note that this embedded Hazelcast instance is used for Vertx clustering. If you want to use Hazelcast also for caching, then you can set up your own Hazelcast cluster and connect to it using Hazelcast (smart) client. No problem with that.

Now, talking about Vertx clustering, depending on what you want to achieve, you have the following options:

1. Use the default embedded Hazelcast

```
ClusterManager mgr = new HazelcastClusterManager();
```

Vertx creates an embedded Hazelcast instance and uses it for clustering.

2. Create your own Hazelcast instance and pass it into `HazelcastClusterManager`

```
HazelcastInstance hazelcastInstance = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance();
ClusterManager mgr = new HazelcastClusterManager(hazelcastInstance);
```

You still use embedded Hazelcast, but this time you have access to the Hazelcast instance. So you can technically do whatever you want with it (e.g. get some distributed map object and put the values into it).

3. Create an embedded Hazelcast and connect it to your other Hazelcast cluster

You can create a separate Hazelcast cluster (as you did with Docker).

```
$ docker run --rm --network host hazelcast/hazelcast
$ docker run --rm --network host hazelcast/hazelcast
```

This may actually not work in Docker Desktop, since Docker Desktop is run in a Virtual Machine that may not support multicast discovery. So you may [install Hazelcast CLI](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-command-line#installation) and start two Hazelcast instances this way.

```
$ hz start
$ hz start
```

Then, make sure you use the same Hazelcast version in your Vertx application and, when started, you should see it connected to the existing Hazelcast cluster.

```
Dec 30, 2020 4:30:11 PM io.vertx.core.impl.VertxImpl
WARNING: You're already on a Vert.x context, are you sure you want to create a new Vertx instance?
HTTP server started on port 8888
...
INFO: [192.168.48.112]:5703 [dev] [4.1] [192.168.48.112]:5703 is STARTING
Dec 30, 2020 4:30:20 PM com.hazelcast.internal.cluster.impl.MulticastJoiner
INFO: [192.168.48.112]:5703 [dev] [4.1] Trying to join to discovered node: [192.168.48.112]:5701
Dec 30, 2020 4:30:20 PM com.hazelcast.internal.server.tcp.TcpServerConnection
INFO: [192.168.48.112]:5703 [dev] [4.1] Initialized new cluster connection between /192.168.48.112:55121 and /192.168.48.112:5701
Dec 30, 2020 4:30:26 PM com.hazelcast.internal.server.tcp.TcpServerConnection
INFO: [192.168.48.112]:5703 [dev] [4.1] Initialized new cluster connection between /192.168.48.112:5703 and /192.168.48.112:37855
Dec 30, 2020 4:30:26 PM com.hazelcast.internal.cluster.ClusterService
INFO: [192.168.48.112]:5703 [dev] [4.1]

Members {size:3, ver:5} [
        Member [192.168.48.112]:5701 - db00aaa1-c46a-4dc1-a1a3-edd823edfaef
        Member [192.168.48.112]:5702 - 9bc4ba13-50d7-4c69-ba2d-2d5fd2e40884
        Member [192.168.48.112]:5703 - 3eb4dcf3-28de-46ef-8f08-49fe0cb1afd3 this
]
```

Comment: What if i want to use all my verticals as lite member and will run other separate pod for hazelcast and register all other members in that pod (Hazelcast pod) for eg: 1) hazelcast as primary gateway with two pods with one standby and two hosted service where all verticles are deployed in both and for each will use two pods but all my cluster map info should be there in hazelcast pod and that will figure out to which pod it actually have to connect based on discovery , load etc